# SELECT unmatched on Android

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell

I have used the following bit of schript to give an options menu but it comes up with a

```
syntax error: 'select' unmatched
```

here is my section of script I couldnt use elif command as android doesn't recognize it.

```
OPTIONS="Continue Quit"
       select opt in $OPTIONS; do
if [ "$opt" = "Quit" ]; then
            echo closing Android Hardening
sleep 5
            exit
fi

if [ "$opt" = "Continue" ]; then

echo       ANDROID
echo      HARDENING

else 
    echo incorrect selection restart application
sleep 7 

exit 1

fi
```

Comment: You're missing a `done` to end the select.

Answer (score 0):

You must close the select ... do with a matching od

Comment: at the end, where the loop finishes